# Qt Heap corruption detected after normal block

Tags: c++, qt, heap-corruption

i have the following situation:

InspectionTreeWidget header:

```
class InspectionTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InspectionTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);



private:

    QVBoxLayout *layout_sourcesettings;

    QFrame *frame_sourcesettings;

...
```

InspectionTreeWidget implementation:

```
InspectionTreeWidget::InspectionTreeWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QTreeWidget(parent)
{
QVBoxLayout *layout_sourcesettings;
     layout_sourcesettings= new QVBoxLayout();

    frame_sourcesettings=new QFrame(this);
    frame_sourcesettings->setLayout(layout_sourcesettings);

...
}
```

everything works well but when i close the application, i get the error "Heap corruption detected after normal block"

what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edit (Solved):**

I don't know if it is a bug or not but the problem was happening because of a sequence in build process:

first i had this code:

```
InspectionTreeWidget::InspectionTreeWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QTreeWidget(parent)
    {

        QVBoxLayout* layout_sourcesettings= new QVBoxLayout();

        frame_sourcesettings=new QFrame(this);
        frame_sourcesettings->setLayout(layout_sourcesettings);

    ...
    }
```

i did a **rebuild** and everythink was ok.

then i move the declaration of layout_sourcesettings to the header and i **build** the project and got not errors compiling but when i close the application i got the heap corruption. But after a **rebuild** i no longer get the heap corruption...

So my question now is: is this a Qt related bug or everytime i move local declarations to header file i have to do a rebuild?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Qt compiled for your compiler? It is not safe to use Qt built with a different compiler. Doing so creates 2 independent heaps where if you allocate memory in 1 heap and try to free it in a second this will corrupt the heap. The crash may not happen on the delete that causes corruption it could happen on some other allocation or deletion so this is hard to debug. For this reason the official releases have binaries for several Visual Studio versions.

Comment: I still think the problem is using a different compiler. This is exactly the kind of random heap corruption behavior you will have when you are using Qt compiled with the wrong version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I understand but i'm using Qt 5.3.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL) and i have visual studio 2013 installed (using visual c++ compiler 12.0)

Comment: Any chance of a different version of Qt installed in your path?

Comment: i used the online installer and installed 2 versions for visual studio 2010 and 2013, so in C:\Qt\5.3\ i have two folders: msvc2010_opengl and msvc2013_opengl. is a problem to have 2 versions installed? Thanks

Comment: Make sure there is no chance the dlls for VS2010 are being loaded by your VS2013 application. Check your path variables...

Comment: after viewing the debug log i think the correct version of dll's are loaded, from vs2013 are xxx120.dll and from Qt  C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_openg\* path

Comment: If the Qt version is not the problem then there is a bug in the code that is not the lines that you posted or at least I do not see a bug in the code you posted. Again remember for heap corruption it can happen some time before you get a heap correct error.

Comment: Make sure you are not doing any double deletes or accessing before an array. What I mean by that is writing to array[-1] can corrupt the heap.